# Calculating, summing and grouping through 3 tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 4 tables: items, orders, inventory_item and inventories.
They are structured like this:

```
 _________         ____________         ________________         _____________
| orders  | >---- |  items     | ----< | inventory_item | >---- | inventories |
|- - - - -|       |- - - - - - |       |- - - - - - - - |       |- - - - - - -|
|+item_id |       |+id         |       |+id             |       |+id          |
|+amount  |       |+group_id   |       |+inventory_id   |        -------------
 ---------        |+worth      |       |+item_id        |       
                  |+min_amount |       |+amount         |
                   ------------         ----------------
```

The inventories table does not need to be queried and is only displayed for understanding the structure.

I would like to have one sql query that is compatible with MariaDB and does the following:
grouped by inventory and group_id display:

- SUM(orders.amount)
- SUM(items.min_amount)
- SUM(inventory_item.amount)
- SUM(items.worth * inventory_item.amount)

I tried to work on that with subqueries, but that seemed hopeless. My current try looks like this:

```
SELECT
    `inventory_item`.`inventory_id`,
    `items`.`group_id`,
    SUM(`items`.`min_amount`),
    SUM(`inventory_item`.`amount`),
    SUM(`inventory_item`.`amount` * `items`.`worth`),
    SUM(`orders`.`amount`)
FROM `items`
INNER JOIN `inventory_item` ON `items`.`id` = `inventory_item`.`item_id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `items`.`id` = `orders`.`item_id`
GROUP BY
    `inventory_item`.`inventory_id`,
    `items`.`group_id`
```

The SUM(orders.amount) value is actually correct, but the others are wrong because one item is counted several times.

I know how to solve that with more than one query, but I would like to do it with only one (MariaDB-compatible) sql query.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help as would a db fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to pre-aggregate the results along one of the dimensions.  I *think* you can do this by pre-aggregating `orders`:

```
SELECT ii.inventory_id, i.group_id,
       SUM(i.min_amount),
       SUM(ii.amount),
       SUM(ii.amount * i.worth),
       SUM(i.amount)
FROM items i JOIN
     inventory_item ii
     ON i.id` = ii.item_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT o.item_id, SUM(o.amount) as amount
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.item_id
     ) o
     ON o.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY ii.inventory_id, i.group_id
```